# Logstash S3 Input NoMethodError

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, logstash

I'm new to logstash and having trouble getting the s3 input to work.  As you can see below, I keep running into this `Error: undefined method common_prefixes for {}:Hash` issue, and I have no idea why.

I am using the latest Logstash from the website, 1.4.2.  I download, untar, run with the config below and get the error listed below.

Am I missing a dependency?  It looks like Logstash bundles everything I should need, including the aws-sdk.

**My config looks like this:**

```
input {
  s3 {
    bucket => "mybucket/withadirectory/"
    credentials => ["id", "key" ]
    codec => "json"
  }
}

output {
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

**Bucket Contents**

```
s3cmd ls s3://mybucket/withdirectory/
2014-11-24 21:43         0   s3://mybucket/withdirectory/
2014-12-08 07:45    729126   s3://mybucket/withdirectory/SampleFileForTesting.gz
```

**Error**

```
Pipeline started {:level=>:info, :file=>"logstash/pipeline.rb", :line=>"78"}
A plugin had an unrecoverable error. Will restart this plugin.
Plugin: <LogStash::Inputs::S3 bucket=>"mybucket/withdirectory/", credentials=>["xyz", "zyx"], region_endpoint=>"us-west-2">
  Error: undefined method `common_prefixes' for {}:Hash
  Exception: NoMethodError
  Stack: /home/test/logstash-1.4.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/aws-sdk-1.35.0/lib/aws/core/data.rb:101:in `method_missing'
/home/test/logstash-1.4.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/aws-sdk-1.35.0/lib/aws/core/data.rb:121:in `method_missing'
/home/test/logstash-1.4.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/aws-sdk-1.35.0/lib/aws/core/response.rb:184:in `method_missing'
/home/test/logstash-1.4.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/aws-sdk-1.35.0/lib/aws/s3/prefix_and_delimiter_collection.rb:31:in `each_member_in_page'
/home/test/logstash-1.4.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/aws-sdk-1.35.0/lib/aws/s3/object_collection.rb:288:in `each_member_in_page'
/home/test/logstash-1.4.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/aws-sdk-1.35.0/lib/aws/s3/paginated_collection.rb:31:in `_each_item'
/home/test/logstash-1.4.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/aws-sdk-1.35.0/lib/aws/core/collection/with_limit_and_next_token.rb:54:in `_each_batch'
/home/test/logstash-1.4.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/aws-sdk-1.35.0/lib/aws/core/collection.rb:80:in `each_batch'
/home/test/logstash-1.4.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/aws-sdk-1.35.0/lib/aws/core/collection.rb:47:in `each'
/home/test/logstash-1.4.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/aws-sdk-1.35.0/lib/aws/s3/object_collection.rb:282:in `each'
/home/test/logstash-1.4.2/lib/logstash/inputs/s3.rb:168:in `list_new'
/home/test/logstash-1.4.2/lib/logstash/inputs/s3.rb:150:in `process_new'
/home/test/logstash-1.4.2/lib/logstash/inputs/s3.rb:137:in `run'
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1521:in `loop'
/home/test/logstash-1.4.2/lib/logstash/inputs/s3.rb:136:in `run'
/home/test/logstash-1.4.2/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:163:in `inputworker'
/home/test/logstash-1.4.2/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:157:in `start_input' {:level=>:error, :file=>"logstash/pipeline.rb", :line=>"168"}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have similar problems in the output plugin, there's a bug in s3 plugin for json format. 
https://logstash.jira.com/browse/LOGSTASH-1643

And I change to 1.5.0, and everything works fine.
Not sure there's the same issue for the input plugin, you can change the codec to plain or switch to 1.5.0 to have a try.

Good luck~